# How to know if a torrent is seeding automatically? 

Tags: bittorrent

I am the director of a short film, I have all the copyright and I want to share my torrent on The Pirate Bay.

I have already uploaded the torrent.

Normally when I do a download, after completed, I seed, but in this case I don't have my torrent in the uTorrent, and I don't have any message about seeding.

This is a new torrent, so, I am the unique person that have the file.

I am seeding automatically?  Or I need do something more?

Comment: 570mb is a short film? How many minutes is it?

Comment: ten. DVD quality @7800 bitrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must load the .torrent file (possibly after downloading it from the site; that varies by site) into your torrent client, then make available to it the file(s) to be torrented.

Comment: yap, it is just define the localization of download to the files. thanks